# HTML - is it still OK to use image rollovers for links?

Tags: validation, html, accessibility, w3c-validation

I have a designer who really wants to use images for fonts in the main site navigation. I'm not sure what ramifications this will have for **validation** and **accessibility**.

The designer tells me as long as we put the text in the Alt tag it will be fine. Can anyone confirm or refute this?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could look into using @font-face for a custom font look in a way that would definitely be accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a designer that is stuck in the dark ages.

Yes, `alt` attributes will be read out by screen readers, so the blind will be find.

However, those that are not using screen readers, but need high-contrast or high levels of zoom will not benefit from this.

Things like embedded links and semantic markup will also be lost (how will one tell an image is supposed to be a header, when you would use an `H1` tag in HTML?).

There are other difficulties in that some text will not be as easily represented within an `alt` attribute as in normal HTML.

This, so far is about accessibility - not sure how validation comes into this (it at all). Can you explain what you mean about validation? If you are talking about valid HTML, then so long as the images have `alt` tags, they would be valid.

There are other ways of using custom fonts within a web page, such as the [`@Font-Face`](http://randsco.com/index.php/2009/07/04/p680) CSS3 selector (which should work in all modern browsers - IE7+ included).

Comment: hey, thanks for the input... what do you mean by "embedded links"?

Comment: @Mark Flint - links. `href`s to other web documents. Like the one with my name just after the -

Answer (score 3):

I'm a screen reader user, and immage links with alt text work well and shouldn't be a problem. If you want to force the user to click on an immage that isn't part of a link though you could have issues since tab navigation between links won't pick up that the user should interact with that specific area of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Slap your designer in the face! :)

Never use images for texts. Use @font-face instead.

You can convert fonts @ http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Search engines need the text as... well.. text.

They will use the alt-text but with much less weight as normal text.

And you really don't have to use images as I already stated use @font-face!

Comment: awesome, never heard of these before. Thanks for enlightening me.

Answer (score 1):

If you go for the images the Alt tag it the way to go but remember it might bring some SEO difficulties, take longer time to load, and might be impractical for some users. ([see also Oded's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512846/html-is-it-still-ok-to-use-image-rollovers-for-links/4512874#4512874))

I would recommend something like the [google font api](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/), it is extremely compatible and you can generate beautiful fonts/text.

There are other options, but I wouldn't say images are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It should as long as it's relativly positioned and follows each other in the proper order in the dom

Comment: If I were to go this route I was hoping to use the images as backgrounds and swap them using CSS hover. Is that bad?